# Display django debug toolbar in production

Tags: django, django-debug-toolbar

I installed django-cahalot with redis backend on my django application. It is working fine on my local machine.
Problem is this I am unable to see any improvement on my production server.
I need to display django-debug-toolbar on my production server to analyze the bottlenecks.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# utils.py 

def show_debug_toolbar_in_staging(*a, **kw):
    return True

# settings.py

SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK = "path.to.utils.show_debug_toolbar_in_staging"
```

should do the trick.

https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html